# How to re-send invitation to write LinkedIn recommendation

Tags: linkedin

Is there a way I can request for recommendation again to the same person?

I have requested them before but from some of them I didn't receive the recommendation. How can I resend the recommendation request (other than sending a private message to them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on ***Profile***.
2. Select ***Recommendations***.
3. Click on ***Manage*** under the appropriate job title.
4. Select ***Request a new or revised recommendation*** underneath the recommendation text .
5. Click ***Save***.